# Program version check and update

Tags: batch-file, find, registry, updates

This site is a wealth of information, and I've found some great solutions, but they're all parts (out of order) for my need.
Adobe has recently issued a security fix for Acrobat, unfortunately it's a minor patch, and also requires the previous patch version.
Detail - In order to update to Acrobat 11.0.08, you must have 11.0.07 installed.
Some machines have 11.0.06 and below. Luckily, 11.0.07 has no prerequisites other than the major version of 11 be installed.

What I need to do is check if the machine has 11.0.07 or 11.0.08. If it does not have either 7 or 8, that 7 be installed, then 8. If 7 is already installed, then have 8 install. If 8 is already installed, do nothing.
Upgrade files are on a share and require admin privileges to install, so it'll be manually run per machine requiring the update.

I hatched the following together -

```
#@echo off
SETLOCAL
cls
rem Installing an update which results in Adobe Reader 11.0.08
echo.
echo.
echo Installing Acrobat Reader 11.0.07 update... please wait...
rem if exist "\\server\share\Logs\%computername%_acrobat_reader_11008.txt" goto gotit
rem Find generates an errorlevel of zero if it encounters a match.
Reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s ^| find  "DisplayName" ^| find "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro" ^| find "DisplayVersion" ^| find "11.0.07"
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
goto got7
) ELSE (
goto wrongversion
)
:got7
echo Installing 11.0.08 Update
Reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s ^| find "DisplayName" ^| find "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro" ^| find "DisplayVersion" ^| find "11.0.08"
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
goto gotit
) ELSE (
net use q: "\\server\share\Source\patches" /persistent:no 
q:
msiexec /quiet /update Q:\AcrobatSecUpd11008.msp > "\\server\share\Logs\%computername%_acrobat_reader_11008.txt"
goto gotit
)
:wrongversion
Reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s ^|find "DisplayName" ^| find "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro" ^| find "DisplayVersion" ^| find "11.0.08"
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
goto gotit
) ELSE (
echo Installing 11.0.07 Update
net use q: "\\server\shareSource\patches" /persistent:no
q:
msiexec /quiet /update Q:\AcrobatUpd11007.msp > "\\server\share\Logs\%computername%_acrobat_reader_11008.txt"
goto got7
)
:gotit
pause
```

Unfortunately, the registry strings values are separated. DisplayName only shows "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro", hence the multiple "find" requests.

Comment: so - is there a question? it seems you have a solution already.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work properly. Ignore some statements. I've tested it on my computer which is at version 08, but it still does the installs.

Comment: Your multiple find statements don't work in the way you think.  The first find with displayname will output text like `Adobe Acrobat XI Pro` and the second find filters on `Adobe Acrobat XI Pro`. The last find only has the `Adobe Acrobat XI Pro` lines as input. Everything else has been filtered out by the previous find command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (` directly contradicts your rem about finds return. i think you mean equ 0 here.

but you should not use this construct anyway, better to use `if errorlevel 1` which tests for 1 **or higher**.

also, if you filter for the displayname, your next filter can't very well find the version number *from these results*.

something along these lines should work:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`Reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /f "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro"`) do (
  SET KEY=%%a
  GOTO :next
)
:next
IF NOT "%KEY%" EQU "" (
  FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,3" %%a in (`Reg query %KEY% /f DisplayVersion`) do (
    IF "%%a" EQU "DisplayVersion" SET VER=%%b
  )
  IF "!VER!" EQU "11.0.07" ECHO found
)
```

Comment: Thank you speising, I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm having trouble injecting it into my current batch.

Comment: it's ok, no need to apologize.

Comment: How would you recommend I implement this? Keeping in mind that If the machine has any version below .07, the 07 patch needs to be installed then 08. But if it has 07, only patch 08 need be installed.

Comment: once you have the version in !VER!, i woul think the logic is quite simple. if !VER! EQU 11.0.07 install 08 etc.

Comment: It is logical, but the problem that I've found with a single search string is if it's not version .07, to install 07... the problem with that is, the !VER! could be 08 and since it's not 07, it'll install 07. So it has to be to have three options if it's not 07 or 07, to install 07, if it's 07, install 08, if it's 08, quit.

Comment: If 6 install 7 if 7 install 8

Comment: If 6 or below install 7, or is that argument possible?

Comment: I got it working! THanks for your help speising. If you're interested or would like to see the final script, I'll post it up here for others.